# How to check if transaction is interact with smart contract or deploying smart contract itself?

Tags: transactions, deployed-bytecode

I'm currently working with go-ethereum,

And unable to use etherscan for this case,

No ABI for me here.

How to check whether if the transaction interacts with/calls a smart contract or deploying the smart contract itself?

And if it deploys the smart contract how can I know the smart contract address deployed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well what you can do is in the geth console you can use the `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(<TX_HASH>)` method to get the transaction receipt. Let's take Chainlink contract creation transaction for example:

[image]

As you can see the `to` value is null and the `contractAddress` value is the value of Chainlink contract. So whenever we have empty `to` value and `contractAddress` is not empty then we're speaking of contract creation.

Contract method requests can be caught with the transaction hash by using method `web3.eth.getTransaction(<TX_HASH>)`. In the response of this method if the `to` value is the contract address and `data` value is not empty ( it has to be valid encoded ABI of the particular method ) then we're definitely speaking for contract method request.